# Getting OLTP like performance from BigQuery results

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working on a project where we need to display BigQuery results in a table within a web application.

We’ve built the feature by paging, sorting and searching directly in BigQuery, but the performance isn’t what you would expect of a modern web application. It takes several seconds the apply a search term or change a page.

I can't really share much code, but this a general question that applies any large resultset generated in BigQuery.

For little bit of context. We create a view in BigQuery by joining a product catalog to orders.

```
WITH Catalog AS
(
  SELECT 
    productId,
  FROM `CatalogTable`
),
Orders AS (
  SELECT 
    p.productId,
    SUM(p.qty) AS qty 
  FROM `OrdersView` as o, o.products AS p 
  GROUP BY p.productId
)
SELECT
  c.productId,
  IF(o.qty IS NULL, 0, o.qty) AS qty,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY qty DESC) as salesRank 
FROM Catalog AS c
LEFT JOIN
 Orders AS o
 ON CONCAT(c.name, c.sku) = CONCAT(o.name, o.sku)
```

And the view is queried like so:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   `catalog` c
LEFT JOIN `catalogView` cv
WHERE  c.name LIKE '%searchTerm%'
LIMIT  10
OFFSET 0
```

What are the options for making this grid-view perform as it would if it were built on a traditional SQL database (or close to the performance)?

I've considered clustering, but i don't believe this is an option since i'm not partitioning the table:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

**NOTES:**

It's acceptable for the results to be a little delayed, if streaming the results into another database is an option.

The query is called via a WebApi endpoint and displayed in an Angular grid-view.

New orders are imported every 15 minutes so the results from this query won't be entirely static, they can change periodically.

The data-grid must support paging, sorting and searching, and the grid could contain 10,000 plus results.

Comment: Can you specify better how is your data, what kind of query you perform and how is your architecture as well??

Comment: I agree with rmesteves, we need more context about your issue, could you please send which queries and dummy/example code have you tried so far.

Comment: Thanks, i've added a little more detail, but i think this answers my question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228532/can-bigquery-be-fast-enough-for-real-time-onsite-request

Maybe there are other options though?

Comment: In fact BigQuery should not be used if you expect an OLTP behavior. If you want to use GCP i'd suggest you to take a look at Cloud SQL and Cloud Spanner  as you can see here https://cloud.google.com/sql/ and here https://cloud.google.com/spanner/

Comment: _Maybe there are other options though?_ How computationally capable are the  webclients? E.g. are the webclients mostly modern laptops or smartphones/old tablets? If it's the former then there could be a way to avoid adding another database as a caching layer .

Answer (score 1):

`BigQuery` should not be used if you expect OLTP behavior or performance.
In your case, if you want to keep your project on `GCP` and also keep your data model as similar as possible with the model you already have, I would suggest you to take a look at [Cloud SQL](http://cloud.google.com/sql) and [Cloud Spanner](http://cloud.google.com/spanner).

Both are fully managed Relational Databases. The main difference is that `Cloud Spanner` is horizontally scalable whereas `Cloud SQL` is not, i.e. if you need only one node, use `Cloud SQL`. If you need to grow up your cluster, use `Cloud Spanner`.

Furthermore, both of them have it's respective Web APIs. You can find the Cloud Spanner Web API reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/). For the Cloud SQL, the reference depends on which DBMS you choose: [SQLServer](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/apis), [MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/apis) or [PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/apis).

I hope it helps